# iOS Swift BLE: Discovering Multiple Characteristics within a Single Service

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, bluetooth

So I am following this iOS App code example from http://www.raywenderlich.com/85900/arduino-tutorial-integrating-bluetooth-le-ios-swift

The code below, taken from the link above, registers one characteristic with the service. How would you register multiple characteristics for one service so that they can be read and written to, using Swift?

```
/* Services & Characteristics UUIDs */
let BLEServiceUUID = CBUUID(string: "025A7775-49AA-42BD-BBDB-E2AE77782966")
let PositionCharUUID = CBUUID(string: "F38A2C23-BC54-40FC-BED0-60EDDA139F47")
let BLEServiceChangedStatusNotification = "kBLEServiceChangedStatusNotification"
.
.
.
.
.
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverServices error: NSError!) {
  let uuidsForBTService: [CBUUID] = [PositionCharUUID]

  if (peripheral != self.peripheral) {
    // Wrong Peripheral
    return
  }

  if (error != nil) {
    return
  }

  if ((peripheral.services == nil) || (peripheral.services.count == 0)) {
    // No Services
    return
  }

  for service in peripheral.services {
    if service.UUID == BLEServiceUUID {
      peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(uuidsForBTService, forService: service as CBService)
    }
  }
}

func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService!, error: NSError!) {
  if (peripheral != self.peripheral) {
    // Wrong Peripheral
    return
  }

  if (error != nil) {
    return
  }

  for characteristic in service.characteristics {
    if characteristic.UUID == PositionCharUUID {
      self.positionCharacteristic = (characteristic as CBCharacteristic)
      peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: characteristic as CBCharacteristic)

      // Send notification that Bluetooth is connected and all required characteristics are discovered
      self.sendBTServiceNotificationWithIsBluetoothConnected(true)
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I think its as simple as just adding more if statements in your for loop. Like this:

```
let characteristicOneUUID= CBUUID(string: "025A7775-49AA-42BD-BBDB-E2AE77782966")
let characteristicTwoUUID= CBUUID(string: "F38A2C23-BC54-40FC-BED0-60EDDA139F47")

for characteristic in service.characteristics {
    //Characteristic One
    if characteristic.UUID == characteristicOneUUID{
      peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: characteristic as CBCharacteristic)
    }
     //Characteristic Two
    if characteristic.UUID == characteristicTwoUUID{
      peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: characteristic as CBCharacteristic)
    }
  }
```